# can gcc warn on assignment of void pointer to more specific pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

How can I make `gcc` warn when a `void*` is assigned or passed as a parameter to a type that is a more specific kind of pointer, like `my_struct*` without a cast? I would like to make sure all casting is explicit.

**Update**: The scope of this question has been extended to non-`gcc` linters as well.

**Update2**: Minuses everywhere? I'm flummoxed by the amount of controversy that a simple, purely technical question can generate.

Comment: Have you read through [GCC's Warnings documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)?

Comment: @GabrieleB-David Yup.

Comment: have you tried using the -Wall flag during compilation and see if it catches that?

Comment: @GabrieleB-David Yes, I have. I always use both `-Wall` and `-Wextra` for my own programs (with `-Wno-unused-function` because that's just too annoying).

Comment: As far as I know, the only flag that has to do with pointer casting is `-Wint-to-pointer-cast` (which is on by default).

Comment: @GabrieleB-David I guess the obvious workaround is `typedef { } opaque_t` and use `opaque_t*` everywhere instead of `void*` but I will leave this open if someone has a better idea or knows of a non-`gcc` linter that can do this check.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David: `void *` can be assiggned to any other pointer type in C. OP asks about warning for a legal expression whihc does not make sense.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: That would violate the effective type rule, thus invoke UB. Just introduce a coding style guide and tgrust your peers. There are enouigh other things in C you can shoot your feet, arms and head. If you already have a problem with that, you should think about using a strongly typed language. Ada comes into mind, or Python (whereas from your question I suspect a dynamically typed language would be a problem of coding discipline, too).

Comment: `-Wc++-compat`, but it will also add a number of other warnings.

Comment: There isn't a clean solution for this. I suggest you stop using void*, and the problem disappears.

Comment: @2501 So what should I use for pointers where I don't know the exact type?

Comment: @DepressedDaniel Can you describe a scenario where you don't know the types of the objects you're defining?

Comment: @2501 When something has to work for arbitrary types, consider, e.g., `qsort`.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel But you know the types in that case. It is just that the information is lost when you pass then to qsort. And at that point you shouldn't care anymore since qsort doesn't return anything.

Comment: If those predefined functions, where you're unable to change their type, are the problem, then define function wrappers, with a proper type, which will give out a warning.

Comment: @2501 Alright, instead of `qsort`, consider `bsearch` ... and defining function wrappers for everything is a lot more overkill than adding a few explicit casts where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make `gcc` warn when a `void*` is assigned or passed as a
>   parameter to a type that is a more specific kind of pointer

Being able to assign a `void *` to a more-specific type without a cast is a *required* part of the C programming language.  Per Paragraph 1 of **6.3.2.3  Pointers** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   object type.**  A pointer to any object  type  may  be  converted  to  a
>   pointer  to `void` and  back  again;  the  result  shall compare equal
>   to the original pointer.

You're asking to be warned about a required part of C.  It's not far removed from asking for a warning when `5` is assigned to an `int`.

As noted by @MarcGlisse, though, [GCC does provide the `-Wc++-compat` warning option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options):

> `-Wc++-compat` (C and Objective-C only)
>
> Warn about ISO C constructs that are outside of the common subset of ISO C and ISO C++, e.g. request for implicit conversion from `void *` to a pointer to non-`void` type.

Comment: Er, you do realize that when things are illegal, compilers try to report errors, and warnings are usually about things that are legal (but suspicious)? Being a "required part of C" is not an argument not to warn. Being a best-practice / common idiom is a better reason.

Comment: @MarcGlisse In C it is not only perfectly acceptable to assign a `void *` pointer *without a cast*, it's actually preferable in many ways. The [highest ranked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/4756299) on [the fourth-highest ranked question on all of Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) specifically states to assign `void *` to specific pointer types *without a cast*.  Casting `void *` is **not** a "best practice" in C, and there are significant arguments for not casting. Again, it's like asking for a warning on `int x = 5;`.

Comment: I agree that warning on this would be wrong. What I said is that "a required part of C" is the wrong argument, what you just wrote in the comment is a much stronger argument.

Comment: @MarcGlisse My point in saying "a required part of C" is that a warning would be absurd on code where the syntax is literally *required* to be supported by the language standard. In this case it's the assignment of a `void *` without a cast to a specific type of pointer. 6.3.2.3 requires that such an assignment can be done in C without a cast.

Comment: The semantics of `a&&b||c` are a required part of C and gcc still warns about missing parentheses. Unused variables are a required part of C and gcc still warns. etc. In first approximation: illegal -> error, legal (but questionable) -> warning.

Comment: @AndrewHenle -1 I don't usually like to be negative but such a warning has clear upsides - the reason I asked this question is because I had just finished spending time debugging a program where the exact problem was that a `void*` was silently cast to a different type without actually being of that type. Since there are pros and cons either way, the choice should rest with the programmer as which kind of error is more likely ultimately depends on the characteristics of the program's design. And as to the argument that it's a required standard - well, so is `gets`. Nuff said.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel *-1 I don't usually like to be negative but such a warning has clear upsides*  The C language mandates that `void *` can be assigned to any type of pointer.  The fact that a programmer *put an incorrect cast in place* is not the fault of the language - and the cast would have eliminated any warning anyway.  Ever hear the phrase ["a bad workman always blames his tools"?](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_bad_workman_always_blames_his_tools)  If C is the wrong tool for you to use - as stated in the comments - **don't use it**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You're not on point with your logic. The problem was not that a programmer *put an incorrect cast in place*. There was no cast at all. `foo* f; bar* b; void* x; x = f; b = x;` succeeds without any cast and that is a Bad Thing.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel *You're not on point with your logic. The problem was not that a programmer put an incorrect cast in place. There was no cast at all. `foo* f; bar* b; void* x; x = f; b = x;` succeeds without any cast and that is a Bad Thing.*  That's ***NOT*** a "bad thing", that's C:  **A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type.**  Again you're blaming the tool for doing *exactly* as the governing standard for that tool says it *must*, And a lot of other programmers believe it is *better* to assign a pointer to `void *` *without* a cast.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is turning into a bit of a flamewar. I'm not blaming the tool, in fact I'm happy with `gcc` since it can actually do the check, and it now enabled in my build. There is a strong technical reason not to want to allow silent conversion of `void*` to any other pointer type - while on the other side the best arguments are "that's the standard" and "other people think it's better [for no articulable reason]". Come on.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel why are you using void* at all? The main point of void* is the implicit conversions. Otherwise, you could just use char*.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Well for arbitrary binary data I don't think `char*` is advisable since it can end up fed into the `str*` functions that operate on null-terminated strings. Really I'm quite happy with the `-Wc++-compat` solution it gives me the right kind of safety net from the type system.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel *I'm not blaming the tool* yet *while on the other side the best arguments are "that's the standard"*?!? The C Standard specifies how this tool must behave to be standard C. Yet you don't like that behavior and want something different? How is that not blaming the tool? So you spent time fixing a bug *where the exact problem was that a `void*` was silently cast to a different type*?  Well, C is an unforgiving tool when the programmer *loses track of what he's working with*. Seems like you want a more forgiving tool, which has already been noted. You seem to *want* not-quite-C.

Answer (score -1):

As noted by @MarcGlisse, `gcc` provides the `-Wc++-compat` warning option. Among other non-`C++`-compatible constructs, it warns about silent conversion of `void*`.

@AndrewHenle linked to an answer to another question which indicates that requiring an explicit cast has the downside of increasing the likelihood that incompatible conversion may result, for example, if the programmer accidentally casts a numeric value.

I think that's significantly less of a concern, since by an explicit cast the programmer certifies that they know what they're doing. Neverthless, even that small drawback can be addressed by using the following macro in conjunction with `-Wc++-compat`:

```
#define VOID_CAST(T, x) ({ __typeof__(x) void_cast_x __attribute__((__unused__)) = ((__typeof__(x))((void*)(x))); ((T*)(x)); })
```

With luck, the "useless" assignment will be optimized out and the benefit of using `VOID_CAST` is that it will generate an error or warning if `x` is not a `void*` to begin with.